# Having difficulty with form data

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have 3 textfields and only one submit button to send all the data of the textfield at once. But how do I send the data of all three textfields at once in php?

```
     <form>
     for($x=0;$x<3;$x++){
     <input type="text" name="name">
     }
     <input type="submit" name="submit">
     </form>
```

Now I have a three fields inside a for loop and I have to extract data from all of them using single submit button.So how can I do that?

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) for some basic information on dealing with forms with PHP

Comment: Can you explain it in greater detail, with code examples? This is too short to be possible to answer.

Comment: I have three fields generated in a loop now I want to extract the data of all three fields with only one submit button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the 'name' attribute on an input allows you to do this for example

```
<form action='submit.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='one'></input>
    <input type='text' name='two'></input>
    <input type='text' name='three'></input>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit!' />
</form>
```

and in your PHP you would do something like this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $inputOne = $_POST['one'];
        $inputTwo = $_POST['two'];
        $inputThree = $_POST['three'];

        //Do whatever you want with them
    }
?>
```

There are better ways of doing this, but this is probably the simplest to understand

---

**If you want all the inputs to have the same name do this**

```
<input type='text' name='textinput[]'></input>
```

Use that instead and loop through all of the inputs like so

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST['textinput'] as $input){
        //do something with $input
    }
?>
```

Comment: Look I have a for loop where a input tag is generated 3 times now I want to extract the data from all three with single submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You put them all inside the same `<form>` and make sure they have different values for the `name` attributes (or that the values end in `[]`).

Comment: Look I have a for loop where I have generated input field three times and now I have to extract the data from all three fields with one submit button.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is this *Note the [ ] behind the name field*

```
<form>
   for($x=0;$x<3;$x++) {
      <input type="text" name="name[]" />
   }
   <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Then to retrieve the values

```
$names = $_POST['name'];
foreach( $names as $name ) {
   print $name;
}
```